# Image on top of a layout

Tags: android, image, floating

[image]

I need to display an image on top of layout just like the one displayed in the link above. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Can you show us your layout file and what you have tried?

Comment: In the above picture, which element do you want on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the top level container a *RelativeLayout*, and add the *rectangle viewgroup*  as a child.

To show the image in that specific position, make it *center_horizontally*, *align _top* with the rectangle, and give it a negative top margin *( margin_top= -halfOfImageHeight/2 )*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you relative layout to easily place the image where you want.

Older versions of Android uses xml entities order to manage elements elevation.
This means you just have to put the image after the layout in your xml file.

In newer Android versions, there's an elevation attribute : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:elevation

Please post you xml code for more details.